# RabbitMQ Java Client Using DefaultConsumer vs QueueingConsumer

Tags: multithreading, rabbitmq, messaging

1. DefaultConsumer
   My DemoConsumer inherits from DefaultConsumer.
   I have noticed that working this way handleDelivery() is invoked from ThreadPool.
   (printing Thread.currentThread().getName() I see pool-1-thread-1/2/3/4 eachtime.
   I have also tested it several times and saw that the order is saved.
   Just to make sure - since different threads call handle delivery - will it mess my order?
2. QueueingConsumer
   All of the java tutorial use QueueingConsumer to consume messages.
   In the API Docs it is mentioned as a deprecated class.
   Should I change my code to inherit from DefaultConsumer use it? Is the tutorial outdated?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "will it mess my order?" ? 
Threads order or Messages order?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes,`DefaultConsumer` uses an internal thread pool that can be changed.
Using `ExecutorService` as:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
Connection conn = factory.newConnection(es);
```

Read http://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html “Advanced Connection options”.

As you can read from the “QueueingConsumer” [doc](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.2.4/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.2.4/com/rabbitmq/client/QueueingConsumer.html):

> As such, it is now safe to implement Consumer directly or to extend DefaultConsumer.

I never used QueueingConsumer, because it isn’t properly event-driven.

As you can see here:

```
QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);
while (true) {
    QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery(); 
    /// here you are blocked, waiting the next message.
    String message = new String(delivery.getBody());
}
```

A typical problem in this case is how to close the subscription, and a common workaround is to send a tagged close message in local host. Actually I don’t like it so much.

If you extend `DefaultConsumer` instead, you can correctly close the subscription and the channel:

```
public class MyConsumer extends DefaultConsumer {...}
```

then

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
MyConsumer consumer = new MyConsumer (channel);
String consumerTag = channel.basicConsume(Constants.queue, false, consumer);
System.out.println("press any key to terminate");
System.in.read();
channel.basicCancel(consumerTag);
channel.close();
....
```

In conclusion, you shouldn’t worry about the message order because if all works correctly, the message order is correct, but I think you can’t assume it because if there is some problem, you can lose the message order. If you absolutely need to maintain message order, you should include a sequential tag to reconstruct the message order at the consumer side.

And you should extend DefaultConsumer.

Comment: Hi, how to do a rateLimiter when extends DefaultConsumer, Since i can't control whether to receive a message or not when extends DefaultConsumer, but when using QueueingConsumer, i can refuse consume before consumer.nextDelivery()

Comment: What happens if we set the thread pool to 1?
    `ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    Connection conn = factory.newConnection(es);`